# LIBTIFF not able to work with C++ project

Tags: c++, libtiff

Libtiff is a C library, but I want to use it with a C++ project in Qt Creator.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I get compile time errors when I try to use the C library, so I'm not sure what to do.

The compile time error I get is:

c:\libtiff\libtiff\tiff.h:69: error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

for the line:
typedef TIFF_INT8_T   int8;

plus a bunch of more similar errors.  Someone please help.

Comment: Instead of trying to compile libtiff as C++, compile it as C, and link it to your C++ code.

Comment: not exactly sure how to do that.  can you guide me through it?

Comment: You need to configure libtiff for building on Windows with the C compiler that matches the C++ compiler you are using. You have to use a C compiler to build libTIFF. To use libTIFF you can use a C++ or C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the include statements on an extern C block --

```
extern "C"{
#include "tiff.h"
}
```

This tells the compiler to view those files as C, not C++, so you should not get strict C++ errors.

Comment: Is it because there is no C compiler available in Qt Creator?

Comment: no sure about Qt Creator, just C/C++ in general.  It could also be a problem in your tiffconf.h.  Did you install and complie libtiff yourself?  It might not be configured properly for your system, specifically the HAVE_INT8/16/32 #defs

Comment: i didn't even compile it.  i just unzipped it into a folder and set the include path in my Qt project file.  How do I "compile" a library?