# UINT8/16/32/etc and INT8/16/32/etc not working in libtiff?

Tags: c++, types, int, libtiff, uint

When I try to run a script with

```
#include "libtiff.h"
```

when compiling, the compiler gives me all sorts of trouble with the UINT and INT data types used in the rest of the LibTiff library.

```
In file included from H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiffio.h:33:0,
             from savetiff.cpp:1:
H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiff.h:68:27: error: expected initializer before 'int8'
  typedef int TIFF_INT8_T   int8;

H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiff.h:69:36: error: expected initializer before 'uint8'
  typedef unsigned int TIFF_UINT8_T  uint8;

H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiff.h:71:27: error: expected initializer before 'int16' 
  typedef int TIFF_INT16_T  int16;

H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiff.h:72:36: error: expected initializer before 'uint16' 
 typedef unsigned int TIFF_UINT16_T uint16;

H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiff.h:74:27: error: expected initializer before 'int32'
 typedef int TIFF_INT32_T  int32;

H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiff.h:75:36: error: expected initializer before 'uint32'
 typedef unsigned int TIFF_UINT32_T uint32;

H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiff.h:77:27: error: expected initializer before 'int64' 
 typedef int TIFF_INT64_T  int64;

H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiff.h:78:36: error: expected initializer before 'uint64' 
 typedef unsigned int TIFF_UINT64_T uint64;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this, other than going into each error message (there are a ton) and fixing everything individually? I am working on Ubuntu, by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that it is the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978225/libtiff-not-able-to-work-with-c-project). Wrap the include in `extern "C" {}`

Comment: Please supply a [MCVE] (that is, a small, complete, self- contained program) that demonstrates this problem.  Then, somone might be able to help you.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solved it.
You need to check the file `H:\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff\tiff.h`. Probably there are some preprocessor definitions that need to be defined by you. In my case, there was a line:

`#ifdef LINUX`

After I defined `LINUX` in another file (in my case, in CMakeLists.txt), the issue was solved.